# How to locate div tags on a website with multiple tabs

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from the following website with multiple info tabs:https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/abt/overview. I am only interested in information under the "ICO" info tabs, but I couldn't locate all div tags under this info tab

I tried find all div tags with class=info-box, but that only returns information contained within the first info tab "Details" on the website. I guess this is because all "ICO" information are hidden when the website is opened. My current code is as follows, which only allows me to extract information from the "Details" table

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time
import re
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/abt/overview"
browser.get(url)


html_source = browser.page_source
data = html_source.encode('utf-8')
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,"lxml")

ICO = soup.find_all("div", class_="info-box")
print (ICO)
```

Please help to locate div tags under the "ICO" info tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a wait condition and attribute = value selector to target the tab for clicking, click it,  then use the css selector combo shown

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get("https://www.cryptocompare.com/coins/abt/overview")
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[aria-controls="tab-content-1"]'))).click()
soup = bs(browser.page_source, 'lxml')
browser.quit()
print([i.text.strip() for i in soup.select('.coin-properties .ng-binding')])
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
page = requests.get(url)
if page.status_code == 200:
   soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
   details = soup.find_all('div', class_ ='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 ng-scope')
```

I haven't tested my code but the above should give you all the info.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I tried and it returned a null list [ ]